# Analyze general log

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, linux, mysql-workbench

**Motivation** : understand the highest CPU\usage\long_query of **historic** queries running on production.

example :10 minute ago on server x graph showed  high CPU usage.

I thougth for next steps :

- Collecting  the slow_query_log  and move to another machine for storage and analyzing
- Analyze production general log for better understanding .With which queries i should handle (active general_log for once a day for 20 minutes  in production)

any better suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the slowlog.  But I also like to crank `long_query_time` down to 1.0 or less.

Use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the log.  This can be done without copying it to another machine.

(Check the arguments to that tool to see if it can limit the output to a given time period.)